# Stop table body from showing above 'sticky' Header

Tags: html, css

I have a single table with a fixed header and scrolling body. The issue is that the body bleeds over the edge of the header when scrolling. Here's a super zoomed in clip of the issue.
does anyone have a solution for this? Plz no plugins or 3rd party solutions.

For the table Im using position sticky on the table row of the header with
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDsA6.png

this is my css for the table

```
.tableFixHead {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 74vh;
    
}
  
.tableFixHead tr th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
.tableFixHead table {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.tableFixHead td:first-child {
    position:inherit;
    left:-1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.tableFixHead {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 74vh;
}

.tableFixHead tr th {
  position: sticky;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
}

.tableFixHead td {
  width: 100vw;
}

.tableFixHead table {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.tableFixHead td:first-child {
  position: inherit;
  left: -1px;
}
```

```html
<p> Sample </p>
<p> Random top content </p>
<table class="tableFixHead">
  <tr>
    <th>head</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see I could not replicate the issue, the sticky header is sticking to the top of the view pane. Are you doing something that is pushing the sticky header down?

Comment: The table is in a div, and does not go all the way to the top of the view pane. There are nav bars above it.